# Vertx API Gateway forwarding multipart/form-data through HttpClientRequest to another vertx micro service is not working

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I am trying to forward a multipart/form-data request to another vertx micro service using HttpClientRequest through a vertx API gateway which is implemented using service discovery. Unfortunately, the request is getting timed out. Request with application/json header is getting forwarded. Any lead to solution is much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Paste the code at least, man